# Parsing parameter from string | regex | php

Tags: php, regex, iptables

I am having problems parsing parameter from a string.

Parameter are defined by the following:

- can be written in short or long notation, p.ex:
  **-a** / **--long**
- characters range from [a-z0-9] for short and [a-z0-9\-] for long notation, p.ex:
  **--long-with-dash**
- can have a value, but don't have to, p.ex: 
  **-a test** / **--aaaa**
- can have multiple arguments, without being in quotes, p.ex:
  **-a val1 val2**
  (that should be captures as one group: value = "val1 val2")
- can have custom text inside quotes
  **--custom "here can stand everything, --test test :( "**
- parameter can have a "!" infront
  **! --test test** / **! -a**
- values can have "-" inside
  **-a value-with-dash**

All these Parameters come in one long string, p.ex:

`-a val1 ! -b val2 --other "string with crazy -a --test stuff inside" --param-with-dash val1 val2 -test value-with-dash ! -c -d ! --test`

-- **EDIT** ----

also `--param value-with-dash`

-- **END EDIT** ---

This is as close as i can get:

https://regex101.com/r/3aPHzp/1

`/(?:(?P<inverted>\!) )?(?P<names>\-{1,2}\S+)($| (?P<values>.+(?=(?: [\!|\-])|$)))/U`

unfortunatly it breaks when it comes to the free text value inside quotes. And when a parameter without value is followed by the next parameter.

(i try to parse the output of iptables-save, in case you are interessted. Also, maybe i split can split the string in an other fancy way before, to avoid a hugh regex, but i don't see it).

Thank you very much for your help!

**-- FINAL SOLUTION --**

for PHP >= 5.6

`(?<inverted>!)?\s*(?<name>--?\w[\w-]*)\s*(?<values>(?:\s*(?:\w\S*|["'](?:[^"'\\]*(?:\\.[^"'\\]*)*)['"]))*)\K`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xSfgxP/1

for PHP < 5.6

`(?<inverted>\!)?\s*(?<=(?:\s)|^)(?<name>\-{1,2}\w[\w\-]*)\s+(?<value>(?:\s*(?:\w\S*|["'](?:[^"'\\]*(?:\\.[^"'\\]*)*)['"]))*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx:

```
(?<inverted>!)?\s*(?<name>--?\w[\w-]*)\s*(?<values>(?:\s*(?:\w\S+|["'](?:[^"'\\]*(?:\\.[^"'\\]*)*)['"]))*)\K
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/3aPHzp/3) (updated)

### Breakdown

```
 (?<inverted> ! )?             # (1) Named-capturing group for inverted result
 \s*                           # Match any spaces
 (?<name> --? \w [\w-]* )      # (2) Named-capturing group for parameter name
 \s*                           # Match any spaces
 (?<values>                    # (3 start) Named capturing group for values
      (?:                           # Beginning of a non-capturing group (a)
           \s*                      # Match any spaces
           (?:                      # Beginning of a non-capturing group (b)
                \w\S+                   # Match a [a-zA-Z0-9_] character then any non-whitespace characters
             |                          # Or
                ["']                    # Match a qoutation mark
                (?:                     # Beginning of a non-capturing group (c)
                     [^"'\\]*               # Match anything except `"`, `'` or `\`
                     (?: \\ . [^"'\\]* )*   # Match an escaped character then anyhthing except `"`, `'` or `\` as much as possible
                )                       # End of non-capturing group (c)
                ['"]                    # Match qutation pair
           )                        # End of non-capturing group (b)
      )*                            # Greedy (a), end of non-capturing group (a)
 )                             # (3 end)
 \K                            # Reset allocated memory of all previously matched characters
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
    
$str = '-a val1 ! -b val2 --custom "string :)(#with crazy -a --test stuff inside" --param-with-dash val1 val2 -c ! -d ! --test';
$re = <<< 'RE'
~(?<inverted>!)?\s*(?<name>--?\w[\w-]*)\s*(?<values>(?:\s*(?:\w\S+|["'](?:[^"'\\]*(?:\\.[^"'\\]*)*)['"]))*)\K~
RE;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r(array_map('array_filter', $matches));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => -a
            [2] => -a
            [values] => val1
            [3] => val1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [inverted] => !
            [1] => !
            [name] => -b
            [2] => -b
            [values] => val2
            [3] => val2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => --custom
            [2] => --custom
            [values] => "string :)(#with crazy -a --test stuff inside"
            [3] => "string :)(#with crazy -a --test stuff inside"
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => --param-with-dash
            [2] => --param-with-dash
            [values] => val1 val2
            [3] => val1 val2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => -c
            [2] => -c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [inverted] => !
            [1] => !
            [name] => -d
            [2] => -d
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [inverted] => !
            [1] => !
            [name] => --test
            [2] => --test
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow, that is so great. Thank you sooo much.
One more thing - it was my mistake, because i just mentioned inside the text, but not in the example. The regex need to match also the a value with a dash:

"**-b value-with-dash**"

Comment: Then please change `\w+` to `[^'"\s]+`.

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work. I am going to try, if i came up with a solution. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Just for record, this works for me now:

`(?<inverted>!)?\s*(?<name>--?\w[\w-]*)\s*(?<values>(?:\s*(?:[\w][\w\-]*|["'](?:[^"'\\]*(?:\\.[^"'\\]*)*)['"]))*)\K`

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for delay, your solution is right but I provided a little more caring one. Check update.

Comment: Had to change the "new" \S+ to \S*, otherwise it don't recognize something like **-a b** anymore.
Hehe, never ending story it seems :). Thanks again for the update.

Comment: i think i go crazy... it works like a charm on the demo site, but i am unable to reproduce the output from there in php. (i click on generate code, but this code produce a different result)
Even when i just copy paste your initial answer, i get now different results, than you posted.

This Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xSfgxP/1

Comment: What is output then?

Comment: nailed it down to 'old' php version 5.5.9, on which it don't work like expected and on 5.6.30, where it worked...

i only got the first 3 matches on 5.5.9, and all matches on 5.6.30 (like the regex101.com).

The problem is, i can not change the php version on the target system :-/

Output: http://pastebin.com/8xREmJsT

Comment: I found a solution for php < 5.6. and updated my first post. Now i am happy :). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using `preview in` feature of https://3v4l.org I don't see a problem with PHP code. Weird.

Comment: i testet it with this code generated by https://regex101.com/r/xSfgxP/1 on https://3v4l.org with php version 5.5.9 (- the default php version for ubuntu 14.04, which is (one of the) target system) - and it shows only 3 matches -> the "\K" was maybe not correctly implemented in this EOL php version. Thats why i had to build a variant without "\K".
But anyway, problem is solved, lets now have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Btw. 5.6.13 is the first php version, which shows correct results with the "\K".

A Look in the PHP changelog: 
Fixed bug #70232 (Incorrect bump-along behavior with \K and empty string match).
Fixed bug #70345 (Multiple vulnerabilities related to PCRE functions).

There it is :D

Comment: That's right. Then you don't need to change whole regex. Just remove `\K`. That would be fine.